# C: read a 2D complex array of a certain format from file

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, scanf, complex-numbers

A 2x2 complex matrix

```
  1+2i 3+4i
  5+6i 7+8i
```

is stored in mat.txt in the format of

```
  (1, 2) (3, 4)
  (5, 6) (7, 8)
```

How to read it to a matrix in C so that

```
  B[0][0].re = 1, B[0][0].im = 2 
  B[0][1].re = 3, B[0][1].im = 4
  B[1][0].re = 5, B[1][0].im = 6 
  B[1][1].re = 7, B[1][1].im = 8
```

?

I have

```
  fptB = fopen("mat.txt","r");
  for(i=0; i <2; i++){
    for (j=0; j<2; j++){
      fscanf(fptB, "(%d, %d)", &B[i][j].re, &B[i][j].im);
    }
  }
  fclose(fptB);
```

but that only reads B[0][0]. Any suggestions on how to modify the code would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
fscanf(fptB, "(%d, %d)%*c", &B[i][j].re, &B[i][j].im);
```